# Bash script returns different results for different users

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-handling, talend

I am trying to check if a particular file is open or not. I am using lsof for this and I am using the bash shell. I have written a bash script to check if the file is open or not. But, I am facing a weird problem. When I run the script from command line using `user a`, I get the expected result. But, when I run the script using `user b`, I get a different result.

I need to call the script from Talend Studio as `user b`, hence I cannot switch to `user a` and execute the script. The script has `777` permissions for `user b` and `user b` is also the owner of the script. Below is the script. Please help.

```
#! /bin/bash
# declare STRING variable

FILENAME=$1
if [ "$FILENAME" == "" ]; then
echo "No file found..exiting"
exit
fi
#While loop to check if the file has been completely copied
while true; do
#$(lsof /mnt/disk1/$FILENAME | wc -l)
SZ=$(/usr/sbin/lsof <Path to file>/$FILENAME | wc -l)
if [ $SZ -gt 1 ]; then
echo "File $FILENAME  is being copied in the Landing Zone"
sleep 10
else
echo "Copied $FILENAME................"
break
fi
done
```

Do I need to add `user b` in the sudoers?

Comment: @Bohemian / @ fedorqui Please help on the above

Comment: What is the expected result, and what is the result you get as user b?

Comment: @chepner While running as "user a", i see "File being copied" as the output, till the file finishes copying and then it prints "Copied <Filename>". When, i run it as "user b", i get "Copied <Filename>", even, when when the file is still being copied

Comment: does userb has permissions on the directory where files are landing and on files

Comment: @garpitmzn yes it does have permissions

Comment: Are you testing with the same `$FILENAME` for both users?  Because the first would copy it, and the second would see that it is already there...

Comment: yes, i am using the same $FILENAME and thats exactly i want. The bash script must echo accordingly. Once, the file is copied, it should say "Copied $FILENAME" else, "File $FILENAME is being copied....".

Answer (score 0):

The aim you use "lsof" is just to verify the $FILENAME is be opened or not , right ?
So I think the better way is to create a flag file when the $FILENAME is opened , but not use "lsof" to verify , because "lsof" is an expensive way to do it . 
For example:

In your "Landing Zone":

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=/foo/foo1
if [ -f /tmp/filename.flag ] ; then
    echo "the file is opened now ..."
else
    touch /tmp/filename.flag
    cp -arf $FILENAME /tmp/. # or use rsync to copy it
    echo "file copy is done ..."
    rm -rf /tmp/filename.flag
fi
```

And , sometime you can just "touch /tmp/filename.flag" to stop this task .